# Combine format objects in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl, excel, format, cpan

Combine format objects in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

I have a format object that sets the background colour, and a second one that sets the number format. If I apply one, then the other to a cell, the second one wipes out the effects of the first one.

i.e. they are mutually exclusive. Is there a nice way to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to apply more than on format to a cell and merge them with [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm).

This is a planned feature for the updated [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm) but it probably won't be back ported to Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Looks like should be using Excel::Writer::XLSX instead of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel anyway.